# How to debug this C program?

Tags: c

What did I do wrong?

I haven't used string library function in this code. I just used index position of the string to solve this code. But when I submit it in URI, it's showing wrong answer.

Problem:

[image]

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, x;
    char s[10], r[10];
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for(i = 0, c = 0; i < x; i++){
        scanf("%s%s", s, r);
        c++;
        if(s[4] == 'a' && r[0] == 'l' || s[4] == 'a' && r[0] == 't'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Bazinga!\n", c);
        }
        else if(s[0] == 'l' && r[4] == 'a' || s[0] == 't' && r[4] == 'a'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Raj trapaceou!\n", c);
        }

        else if(s[0] == 'p' && r[4] == 'a' || s[0] == 'p' && r[0] == 's'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Bazinga!\n", c);
        }
        else if(s[4] == 'a' && r[0] == 'p' || s[0] == 's' && r[0] == 'p'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Raj trapaceou!\n", c);
        }

        else if(s[0] == 't' && r[0] == 'p' || s[0] == 't' && r[0] == 'l'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Bazinga!\n", c);
        }
        else if(s[0] == 'p' && r[0] == 't' || s[0] == 'l' && r[0] == 't'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Raj trapaceou!\n", c);
        }

        else if(s[0] == 'l' && r[0] == 's' || s[0] == 'l' && r[0] == 'p'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Bazinga!\n", c);
        }
        else if(s[0] == 's' && r[0] == 'l' || s[0] == 'p' && r[0] == 'l'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Raj trapaceou!\n", c);
        }

        else if(s[0] == 's' && r[0] == 't' || s[0] == 's' && r[4] == 'a'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Bazinga!\n", c);
        }
        else if(s[0] == 't' && r[0] == 's' || s[4] == 'a' && r[0] == 's'){
            printf("Caso #%d: Raj trapaceou!\n", c);
        }
        else if(s[4] == 'a' && r[4] == 'a' || s[0] == 'p' && r[0] == 'p' || s[0] == 't' && r[0] == 't' || s[0] == 'l' && r[0] == 'l' || s[0] == 's' && r[0] == 's'){
            printf("Caso #%d: De novo!\n", c);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the sample input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the index `[2]` of `s` and `r`:

```
d: pedra
p: papel
s: tesoura
g: legarto
o: spock
```

Then the response would be

```
novo: 

s[2] == r[2]

bazinga:

s[2] == 's' && r[2] == 'p'
s[2] == 'p' && r[2] == 'd'
s[2] == 'd' && r[2] == 'g'
s[2] == 'g' && r[2] == 'o'
s[2] == 'o' && r[2] == 's'
s[2] == 's' && r[2] == 'g'
s[2] == 'g' && r[2] == 'p'
s[2] == 'p' && r[2] == 'o'
s[2] == 'o' && r[2] == 'd'
s[2] == 'd' && r[2] == 's'

trapaceou: otherwise.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now the code is accepted.
But could you please explain why the previous one was not accepted??
I didn't find any problem. What was the problem actually?

Comment: To be honest, i don't know, simply intuition, i saw unecessary complexity, just brought it down to a simpler version. I trusted your statement, that it didn't work and didn't debug your code, sorry.